# JSON serialized output has C# escaped formatting

Tags: c#, json, rest, formatting, .net-4.5

I am trying to POST an updated object to REST server API from my client. I am using RestSharp and I am adding JSON representation of my object to the body of my request. However, my string representation of the serialized object has wrong format. The server rejects it.

My request looks something like this (I used Fiddler to get it)

```
PUT https://myapp.net/api/PriceListItems/151276 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/104.4.0.0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: myapp.net
Content-Length: 75
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

"{\"Id\":151276,\"AgendaId\":0,\"CurrencyId\":1,\"Code\":\"\",\"Price\":7.0}"
```

I have tried to serialize my object with Json.NET, RestSharp's internal Json serializer and with JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Script.Serialization. All return a string in such format. I know that the reason for such formatting is because C# escapes double quotes so it can display it properly inside, but i dont understand how am I supposed to pass it to my request without this escaped formatting. I know for a fact that properly formed JSON is accepted by the server.

The object that I am trying to serialize looks like this

```
public class PriceListItem
    {
        public static PriceListItem CreatePriceListItem(int id, int agendaId, int currencyId, string code, string unit, decimal price)
        {
            var priceListItem = new PriceListItem
            {
                Id = id,
                AgendaId = agendaId,
                CurrencyId = currencyId,
                Code = code,
                Price = price
            };
            return priceListItem;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AgendaId { get; set; }

        public int CurrencyId { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

EDIT:
Moved my solution from here to answers.

Comment: Seems like you have a double-serialization. Couldn't you show the PUT Action of your Controller too?

Comment: Yes, double serialization was exactly my problem. I was just adding info to my original post to include that information. Thank you.

Comment: @filipv you might want to move your solution (that it was double-serialized) down into an answer and accept it. Then people having this problem in the future will be better-able to find your solution.

Comment: @Ghukas allright, I did as you suggested and moved my solution

Comment: Good decision, btw it was @MatthewHaugen who suggested you to do so.

Comment: I'm so sorry I must read more carefully. Anyway, @MatthewHaugen thank you for suggesting my solution as an answer.

Comment: I know that feeling, needing to read more carefully. Now you should remember to accept that answer, too! :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just read another topic on this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772002/escape-characters-after-serializing-using-json). The problem was that I serializing the object twice.

Instead of

```
request.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(priceListItem));
```

I should have used

```
request.AddBody(priceListItem);
```

Anyway, maybe it will help someone else. I find it strange however that the object is serialized automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem, and my workaround was to create a JObject with Newtonsoft and pass that.

Either:

```
JObject jBytes = Object.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, MyDateTimeFmtString);
```

or

```
JObject jBytes = JObject.FromObject(myObject, MyJsonSerializer);
```

The first case was my second choice, but I think there is a bug in Newtonsoft where JObject.FromObject ignores the DateFormatString in JsonSerializer.