# JSON Serialization adding extra character as "\"

Tags: c#, json, string, wcf, json.net

I have a string like this which I got from report expression:

```
 jql = @"(Project in (""CI"") and Status in (""Open"") and issueType in (""Action Item"")) or issueKey = ""GR L-1"" order by Created asc";
```

I converted it to JSON and get the result like this:

```
 jql = jql.Replace("\"", "'");
 jql = "{" + "\"" + "jql" + "\"" + ": " + "\"" + jql + "\"" + "}";
```

to get below JSON:

```
   {"jql": "(Project in ('CI') and Status in ('Open') and issueType in ('Action Item')) or issueKey = 'GR L-1' order by Created asc"}
```

When I'm doing serializasion like this:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

Its giving me sting like this:

```
 {"jql":"{\"jql\": \"(Project in ('CI') and Status in ('Open') and issueType in ('Action Item')) or issueKey = 'GR L-1' order by Created asc\"}","startAt":0,"maxResults":0,"fields":[]}
```

and this is kind of wrong string. Actually I want a string like this:

```
{"jql": "(Project in ('CI') and Status in ('Open') and issueType in ('Action Item')) or issueKey = 'GR L-1' order by Created asc"}
```

Note: I need to do request like this:

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
request.JQL = jql;
 string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
 string result = runQuery(JiraResource.search, data, "POST");
```

I tried like this : [Escape characters after Serializing using Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772002/escape-characters-after-serializing-using-json) 
However, this is not working...

Actually I want a string like this:

```
{"jql": "(Project in ('CI') and Status in ('Open') and issueType in ('Action Item')) or issueKey = 'GR L-1' order by Created asc"}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for your case:

```
string jql = @"(Project in (""CI"") and Status in (""Open"") and issueType in (""Action Item"")) or issueKey = ""GR L-1"" order by Created asc";
jql = jql.Replace("\"", "'");
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { jql = jql } );
```

resulting the output

> {"jql":"(Project in ('CI') and Status in ('Open') and issueType in ('Action Item')) or issueKey = 'GR L-1' order by Created asc"}

as intended.

Comment: That is exactly what i did previously. Any way, Thanks for answer.